# Who sets the SkipOffset value in VAST tags?

Tags: ads, vast, advertisement-server

Who sets the SkipOffset value in VAST tags, is it by the Advertiser from DSP or Publisher from SSP? Or else it should be set from the player?

```
<Creative>
    <Linear skipoffset=”00:00:05”>…</Linear>
</Creative>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is set by the Advertiser from DSP or in short - the one that creates the ad is responsible for the "SkipOffset".

Additionally, the Player can have a default value if the "SkipOffset" is not presented in the VAST tag.

Comment: How do you add the default offset? I don't see this in their docs (https://docs.fluidplayer.com/docs/configuration/ads/)

Comment: Maybe Fluid Player does not support the default value for "skipoffset". As I mainly work with JWPlayer, I can confirm that JWPlayer has this functionality: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference

Comment: I was able to add default skipoffset value to my fluid-player: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69162245/add-default-skip-offset-to-fluid-player/69163113#69163113