# Add default skip offset to fluid player

Tags: javascript, video, vast

fluid-player displays the "skip ad" button if the ad has an attribute `skipoffset` ([see here](https://github.com/fluid-player/fluid-player/blob/master/src/modules/vast.js#L494)). I'm trying to create client code that injects a default `skipoffset` to the ad so that I show the skip button even if the ad doesn't have a pre-configured skip interval.

I tried overriding the player's functions `onBeforeXMLHttpRequestOpen` and `onBeforeXMLHttpRequest`, and using those to inject a value to the responseXML, but because `request.onreadystatechange()` handles the `skipoffset` extraction, and `onreadystatechange` calls into private methods of the playerInstance, I can't override it through the external api `onBeforeXMLHttpRequestOpen` or `onBeforeXMLHttpRequest`.

Any thoughts on where I can inject this default value?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out the missing bit:
I was attempting to override the provided `onreadystatechange` by re-assigning this method with my own function, and than calling into the provided method.

```
onBeforeXMLHttpRequestOpen: request => {
  let defaultOnReadyStateChange = request.onreadystatechange;
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.responseXML != null) {
      let linearElements = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Linear');
        if (linearElements != null && linearElements.length) {
          linearElements[0].setAttribute('skipoffset', '00:00:05');
        }
      }
    defaultOnReadyStateChange();
};
```

By doing so I would get an error because when calling into `defaultOnReadyStateChange`, the context of the call would change and internal attributes for xmlHttpRequest would be missing.

The solution would be the above code, but the 2nd line should be

```
let defaultOnReadyStateChange = request.onreadystatechange.bind(request);
```

This works for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The other method didn't work for me, so I have hosted the fluidplayer js file on my server and changed 1 line of code to show a default skip ad button in case the vast url ad provider didn't define a skipoffset attribute.
search for:

```
n.skipoffset
```

-don't worry you will get one result :)-.
then change what is equal to:

```
(typeof e.convertTimeStringToSeconds(u.getAttribute("skipoffset")) == 'undefined') ? e.convertTimeStringToSeconds(u.getAttribute("skipoffset")) : 5),
```

and voila that is it.